Mac Silicon native support for Julia LTS (1.6.7 (July 19, 2022)) not existent
Is there a channel that I can use in juliaup for Julia LTS (currently 1.6.7 (July 19, 2022)) on Mac silicon?
If I do:
juliaup list | grep aarch64 

at my terminal I get:
 1                      1.10.2+0.aarch64.apple.darwin14        
 1.7.0                  1.7.0+0.aarch64.apple.darwin14         
 1.7.0-beta3~aarch64    1.7.0-beta3+0.aarch64.apple.darwin14

 ...

 release~aarch64        1.10.2+0.aarch64.apple.darwin14        
 nightly                latest-macos-aarch64                   
 nightly~aarch64        latest-macos-aarch64 

If there isn't (how) can I install the current LTS using juliaup?
I am on on MBP M3Max + Sonoma.

could you try to run it under rosetta?

@DanielA.White. Yes I could, but that's not the question. Thanks though.

You can always just download the binaries, put them in the path or use symlinks. Works perfectly, the biggest advantage of juliaup is on Windows, in Linux or Mac just use symlinks, it's the same...

Is Julia 1.6 distributed for Mac as aarch64 at all? The dmg for download from https://julialang.org/downloads/#long_term_support_release is x86_64.
